# maven deploy jar to svn with a commit message

Tags: svn, maven, maven-deploy-plugin

We use a maven repo managed in a SVN. I am built a jar `newUtil-1.0.jar` which I need to deploy it to the remote repo. I am using the following command, which results in build failure.

> `mvn deploy:deploy-file -Dfile=/tmp/newUtil-1.0.jar -DgroupId=com.tareque.utils -DartifactId=newUtil -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar -DrepositoryId=myrepo -Durl=https://<my-repo-url>`

Checking the logs at the server side for `svn` shows this message

> [Fri Jan 18 11:35:47 2013] [error] [client 169.124.140.200] Commit blocked by pre-commit hook (exit code 1) with output: \nEmpty comments are not allowed.

by which it seems that commit's with empty messages/comments are blocked.

So, how do I pass a comment for the commit message to the above `maven deploy` command?

Comment: Why not using a real repository manager instead of SVN. What's the advantage of a SVN as a repository over a Repo manager?

Comment: @khmarbaise I am the new developer to the team. This has been used since years. So, changing that is another big task. Hope you get, it's the actual developer world and not the ideal one in which developer got the complete access ;)

Comment: The usual way to deploy a jar is to use the maven-release-plugin which will tag in SVN etc. and of course will deploy the artifact to the appropriate repository. But you can try to use -Dmessage="WhatEver", but i'm not sure if this works.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use deploy, use `maven-release-plugin`.  Setting up the commit message in this case is easy:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <scmCommentPrefix>re #123:</scmCommentPrefix>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>  ......
```

You'll have to search around a bit for whatever other settings you need to use the release plugin in the first place (`<scm>` and `<distributionManagement>` tags, for a start) but once you have `mvn release:prepare release:perform` working, this extra configuration setting will let you modify the commit message.

Trust me, once you use the release plugin properly you won't want to go back to hand-rolling releases.

ETA: if you are in fact trying to deploy *snapshots* to SVN (this seems kind of nuts and I've never seen it done, but it should be possible) you'd want to investigate [using `wagon-scm`](http://maven.apache.org/wagon/wagon-providers/wagon-scm/usage.html) such that your `<distributionManagement>` section would use `scm:svn:https://your-repo-url`.  If you get it working, please let us know!

Comment: This will, however, make a tag on every commit.

Comment: Well, the point is that you're *releasing*, hence the name of the plugin, and you certainly should tag each release.  If the OP isn't "cutting a release", they should be using a SNAPSHOT version ID, and the answer would change.

Comment: Yeah, you are indeed correct. I believe mtk was unaware of how `SNAPSHOT`-s and fixed version releases work in Maven.